# CSS only loading animations not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have tried an animation using **box-shadow**. If you note that red color box-shadow is repeating twice to and fro. I doubt whether it happens due to **animation-direction:alternate** property or due to wrong box-shadow properties. Could you please correct me on what wrong i'm doing. Hope you understand my query.

```css
.loader{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:#0388db;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:boxShadow 2s linear infinite alternate;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px #0388db;
}
@keyframes boxShadow{
  0%{
        box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  25%{
    box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-48px 0 0px -2px red,48px 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  50%{
    box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
  }

  75%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -2px red,0 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  100%{
    box-shadow:0 0 3px #0388db;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">

</div>
```

Please refer the working fiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/36pa19fz/1/)**

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/nao9apwt/1/

Comment: @Santhosh Kumar  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-direction.check this url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.loader{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:#0388db;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:boxShadow 2s linear infinite forwards;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px #0388db;
}
@keyframes boxShadow{
  0%{
        box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  25%{
  box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-48px 0 0px -2px red,48px 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  50%{
  box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red, 24px 0 0px -2px red;
  }

  75%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -2px red,0 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  100%{
      box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">

</div>
```

use `animation-timing-function` as `forwards`,

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

You should change code line of 0% and 25%

red cycle in 0% should be -48 and 48 px and in 25% should be -24 and 24 px

```css
.loader{
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 background:#0388db;
 border-radius:50%;
 margin:50px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 animation:boxShadow 2s linear infinite alternate;
 box-shadow:0 0 3px #0388db;
}
@keyframes boxShadow{
 0%{
  box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-48px 0 0px -2px red,48px 0 0px -2px red;
 }
 25%{
  box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
 }
 50%{
  box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
 }
 75%{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -2px red,0 0 0px -2px red;
 }
 100%{
  box-shadow:0 0 3px #0388db;
 }
}
```

```html
  <div class="loader">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

animation-direction:alternate property not suit for this example. remove it.

```css
.loader{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:#0388db;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:boxShadow 2s linear infinite;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px #0388db;
}
@keyframes boxShadow{
  0%{
        box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  25%{
    box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-48px 0 0px -2px red,48px 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  50%{
    box-shadow: -24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,24px 0 0px -1px #0388db,-24px 0 0px -2px red,24px 0 0px -2px red;
  }

  75%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -1px #0388db,0 0 0px -2px red,0 0 0px -2px red;
  }
  100%{
    box-shadow:0 0 3px #0388db;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">

</div>
```